# To those who know Sanskrit, what exactly is the mystery of Yajur Veda chapter 23?

Tags: vedas, rituals, yajur-veda, sacrifice, shukla-yajurveda

Chapter 22-25 is supposed to contain ashwamedha sacrifice. As I have heard, Hindus and non-Hindus have a secretive debate about this because this sacrifice is said to have bestiality as per non-Hindus while Hindus defend by saying it is supposed to be symbolic. Then why so much secrecy? The Rig Veda is so famous, there are lots of translations, which are pretty much the same and non-controversial. But when it comes to Yajurveda, I couldn't find any proper English translation at all.

I found two translations in archives - one by someone named Satya Prakash Saraswati and another from Arya Samaj. The Satya Prakash one was weird, had references of 'spacecraft' and 'machines' and all. The Arya Samaj interpretation was highly diluted, even without knowing Sanskrit, I could understand this much. It talks about 'national economy' and 'governance machinery' in these verses. It uses flowery language and doesn't even seem to make it look like a sacrifice is described at all. You can definitely say that the sacrifice in Yajurveda is symbolic but deleting the whole reference to sacrifice to English readers is not right and makes it look more suspicious.

I looked at other verses, and it had very very weird stuff like 'this animals belongs to the moon, that animal belongs to the Sun, that thing belongs to Prajapati'. That looks like cryptic language, so I am willing to accept that the sacrifice mentioned in Yajur Veda is indeed a symbolic one. But I want an accurate transliteration. I want to know exactly what is written in Yajur Veda, especially Chapter 23 where it seems from these bad translations that a horse being sacrificed is being talked about but vaguely. Does anyone with a knowledge of Sanskrit please provide accurate translation/transliteration please?

Edit: I will provide the two weird translations I found:

https://archive.org/details/yajurveda-english-translation

https://archive.org/details/yajurvedenglishtulsiram/page/n829/mode/2up

Comment: Not a forum for translating sanskrit.